# MySQL Select with CASE AND Group By

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL statement which collects data for me from 3 tables.

The tables have the following structure:

**travel_plan**

```
#   Name        Type            
1   id          int(11)         
2   plan        varchar(11)         
3   created_at  timestamp               
4   updated_at  timestamp       
5   created_by  int(11)                 
6   updated_by  int(11)             
7   eligibility varchar(50)     
8   lower_limit int(11)             
9   upper_limit int(11)
```

**plan_category**

```
#   Name        Type    
1   idPrimary   int(11)         
2   category    varchar(255)            
3   created_at  timestamp                   
4   updated_at  timestamp       
5   updated_by  int(11)             
6   created_by  int(11)
```

**plan_category_detail**

```
#   Name                Type    
1   idPrimary           int(11) 
2   plan_category_id    int(11)         
3   travel_plan_id      int(11)     
4   description         varchar(255)        
5   created_at          timestamp           
6   updated_at          timestamp
7   created_by          int(11)     
8   updated_by          int(11)
```

And this is my SQL query:

```
SELECT 
  plan_category.id,
  plan_category.category AS OPTION,
  CASE
    WHEN plan = 'Business' THEN plan_category_detail.description
    ELSE ''
  END AS Business,
  CASE
    WHEN plan = 'Holiday' THEN plan_category_detail.description
    ELSE ''
  END AS Holiday,
  CASE
    WHEN plan = 'Schengen' THEN plan_category_detail.description
    ELSE ''
  END AS Schengen,
  CASE
    WHEN plan = 'Student' THEN plan_category_detail.description
    ELSE ''
  END AS Student,
  CASE
    WHEN plan = 'Senior' THEN plan_category_detail.description
    ELSE ''
  END AS Senior,
  CASE
    WHEN plan = 'Incoming' THEN plan_category_detail.description
    ELSE ''
  END AS Incoming,
  CASE
    WHEN plan = 'East Africa' THEN plan_category_detail.description
    ELSE ''
  END AS East_Africa
FROM
  travel_plan
    INNER JOIN
  plan_category_detail ON plan_category_detail.travel_plan_id = travel_plan.id
    INNER JOIN
  plan_category ON plan_category.id = plan_category_detail.plan_category_id
GROUP BY plan_Category_detail.id , plan_category.id;
```

And it gave me the  following output :

```
"1" "LIMIT (Medical Expenses and Related Expenses)" "300,000"   ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
"1" "LIMIT (Medical Expenses and Related Expenses)" ""  "200,000"   ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
"1" "LIMIT (Medical Expenses and Related Expenses)" ""  ""  "80,000"    ""  ""  ""  ""
"1" "LIMIT (Medical Expenses and Related Expenses)" ""  ""  ""  "75,000"    ""  ""  ""
"1" "LIMIT (Medical Expenses and Related Expenses)" ""  ""  ""  ""  "100,000"   ""  ""
"1" "LIMIT (Medical Expenses and Related Expenses)" ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "120,000"   ""
"1" "LIMIT (Medical Expenses and Related Expenses)" ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  "30,000"
```

However, I want an output of the following type :

```
"1" "LIMIT (Medical Expenses and Related Expenses)" "300,000"   "200,000"   "80,000"    "75,000"    "100,000"   "120,000"   "30,000"
```

How can I achieve the above output?

I also tried `GROUP BY` function but still couldn't work. Kindly help

Comment: Do you really require the output to be perfect in MySQL itself? Since you're using PHP, you could format the output in PHP. You can do this even without any `CASE WHEN` in MySQL, with a very simple query. PHP is just a bit more flexible when it comes to formatting output.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `conditional aggregation` here so just use `max()` in your case expression

```
    SELECT plan_category.id,plan_category.category AS OPTION,
           max(CASE WHEN plan ='Business' THEN plan_category_detail.description ELSE '' END) AS Business,
           max(CASE WHEN plan ='Holiday' THEN plan_category_detail.description ELSE '' END) AS Holiday,
           max(CASE WHEN plan ='Schengen' THEN plan_category_detail.description ELSE '' END) AS Schengen,
           max(CASE WHEN plan ='Student' THEN plan_category_detail.description ELSE '' END) AS Student,
           max(CASE WHEN plan ='Senior' THEN plan_category_detail.description ELSE '' END) AS Senior,
           max(CASE WHEN plan ='Incoming' THEN plan_category_detail.description ELSE '' END) AS Incoming,
           max(CASE WHEN plan ='East Africa' THEN plan_category_detail.description ELSE '' END) AS East_Africa
FROM travel_plan INNER JOIN plan_category_detail ON plan_category_detail.travel_plan_id = travel_plan.id 
INNER JOIN plan_category ON plan_category.id = plan_category_detail.plan_category_id  
GROUP BY plan_Category_detail.id , plan_category.id
```